# How to display resource object in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-resource

I have a problem with displaying records in angular...
query like this..
Angular Controller

```
        angular.module('MyApp')
                .controller('CountriesCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, Countries) {




           Countries.query({}, function (countries) {
  //Countries.get() return Expected response to contain an object but got an array so i use  countries.query....

                            $scope.countries = countries;
                            console.log(countries);


                        });
                    })
```

which returns
[image]

.. Using the returned data How can I show in angular with ng-repeat..

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-repeat over the array:

```
<div ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <span>{{country.name}}</span>
</div>
```

I suggest anyway to follow some good tutorial and the documentation: this is pretty much basic stuff. Documentation on ng-repeat can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)